# Why does Xamarin.Forms databinding work for one control but not another?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xaml-binding

I am developing a Xamarin app which I am testing on an Android device. I have a XAML view and I am binding an enum property in the viewmodel to multiple controls - one for text value, and the other to background color with an IValueConverter. Relevant XAML code:

```
<ContentView
  BackgroundColor="{Binding MyField, Converter={StaticResource MyFieldEnumValueToColorConverter}}"
>
    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding MyFieldClickCommand}" />
    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    
    <Label
        Text="{Binding MyField}"
    />
</ContentView>
```

IValueConverter implementation:

```
public class MyFieldEnumValueToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is MyFieldEnum)
        {
            switch ((MyFieldEnum)value)
            {
                case MyFieldEnum.Value1:
                    return Color.Orange;
                case MyFieldEnum.Value2:
                    return Color.Green;
                case MyFieldEnum.Value3:
                    return Color.Red;
            }
        }

        return Color.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Property in the viewmodel (yes, it does implement INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private MyFieldEnum _myField;

public MyFieldEnum MyField
{
    get => _myField;
    set
    {
        _myField= value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyField)));
    }
}
```

When I load this page, the controls load properly for every distinct enum value: the text and the background color both reflect the actual value.

In a click handler, I simply set the property value like this:

```
MyField = MyFieldEnum.Value2;
```

The text changes, but the background color does not. Why?

I also tried introducing a new field (of type Color), implement the IValueConverter logic directly in the getter, and bind that to the BackgroundColor attribute of the ContentView. Same issue. The page has many other data-bound items and all work properly except this one.

UPDATE: it appears that the problem is with the ContentView. I put the exact same BackgroundColor binding to the Label itself and there it works as expected, but for the ContentView it does not.

Comment: why are you using `_name` for the backing field?

Comment: @Jason I copied it wrong, I updated the question.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. It should work without the following, but try this: `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => MyField = MyFieldEnum.Value2 );` That's the first thing I try when Xamarin.Forms fails to respond to an update.

Comment: Just asking for completeness, but did you confirm you defined your converter in the resource dictionary, either at the page or application level?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks. I tried it, it still does not work. I find it very strange that the text changes but the background color does not.

Comment: @Andrew yes:

`xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:App.Core.Converters"`

and:

`<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:MyFieldEnumValueToColorConverter x:Key="MyFieldEnumValueToColorConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>`

Comment: Update: if I put the backgroundcolor on the Label itself instead of (or along) the ContentView, that updates as expected. It's interesting to see that the exact same binding works for one control but not the other. This seems like a bug to me, or there's something specific with the ContentView that I'm missing.

Comment: That does sound like a bug. Or at least a surprising implementation decision. Sounds like ContentView either defaults its Bindings to `OneTime` (do not dynamically update), or else has a bug such that it fails to redisplay itself when a binding changes. You could report it as an issue at `github maui issues`. If interested in testing, try `BackgroundColor="{Binding ..., BindingMode=OneWay}". This should be a dynamic binding. If that doesn't fix, then its definitely a bug.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks, that is a good idea. I tried it and it still does not work with explicit binding mode set in the XAML. I'm gonna try to narrow it down some more before reporting an issue (first I'm trying different layout controls instead of the ContentView).

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the underlying cause.

The ContentView also has a style defined in a StaticResource which adds a few styling rules to the control (background color included). I conveniently omitted this style from my question for brevity. I figured this might be an issue so I removed the background color from the style, but the problem persisted. I fiddled with XAML attribute order as I remember that it gave me a hard time before, but no luck there either.

I looked closer at the defined styles and I found that the style includes a Xamarin.Forms RoutingEffect for a rounded corner with a configurable radius. Upon examining the Android-specific implementation of the code I realized that it achieves the corner radius it sets the background color to transparent and sets the container layer's background color to the original background color and the corner radius. It is my understanding that this piece of code runs once when the element is rendered (OnAttached). The initially bound background color is correct because it is applied before, but it is overridden and I believe that the binding is overridden/removed when the effect sets the view's background color to transparent.

I confirmed this being the root cause by removing the effect from the element, and it started working as expected. Of course, I lost the rounded corners for this element, which makes the UI inconsistend, but that is a problem for another day. Thanks for everyone for the suggestions!

Comment: For rounded corners you can use a Frame or a PancakeView (https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView)

Comment: Super, you can add some code to your post and then check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.